# Having trouble assigning values to 2-D "Dynamically Created" array in c++

Tags: c++

I'v created a dynamic 2 dimension integer array, but when I assign values to any of its index it gives an error
This is my code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int row,col;
    row=col=5;
    int **ptr1;
    ptr1=new int *[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        ptr1[i]=new int[col];

    int i=4;
    int j=2;
    ptr1[i,j]=5;

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the error "error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Comment: Your code doesn't contain `>>`, so it isn't related to your error. Show the code that actually causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ptr1[i][j]=5;` instead of `ptr1[i,j]=5;`